# How to save custom product tab fields drop box and input text value to database in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, adminhtml, controllers, product-edit

Overrided Admin Product Save Controller (shown below)

```
<?php

namespace Maxime\Helloworld\Controller\Adminhtml\Rewrite\Product;

class Save extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product
{

    public function execute()
    {
    $productId = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

    print_r($_POST);die();
    return parent::execute();
    }
}
```

In my phtml page, listed out a input field and a select/option field inside a form. 
I tried a lot of times to paste the code.But it didn't appears.
I need to get the values of both fields in that overrided controller.

Comment: Use `print_r($data)` to print the form values because you are storing your postvalues in `$data` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the values in post by using the following in select tag.

```
data-form-part="product_form"
```