# How to save custom product tab drop box fields values to database in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, adminhtml, save, drop-downs

By using data-form-part="product_form" in input tag, text values are getting. But how gets the drop down values.

When i used data-form-part="product_form" same in option, it gives an array with key index [undefined] and always give its last value of dropdown

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save custom product tab fields drop box and input text value to database in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175609/how-to-save-custom-product-tab-fields-drop-box-and-input-text-value-to-database)

Comment: You might consider changing the title of your post and linking to the original question + answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the values in post by using the following in select tag.

```
data-form-part="product_form"
```